# Eliminating redundant relationships when modeling Header/Detail relationships?

Tags: data-modeling

I've got a model that looks something like this:

[image: Model]

One Account has many Branches, and each Statement is generated for one Account.  The model is redundant because the Account (the AccountID on the header) can be inferred from the BranchID on a transaction (a statement will always have one or more transactions).

Should the AccountID be removed from the StatementHeader, or is this level of redundancy OK?  Or is there a better solution?

Comment: I would avoid using "ID" as the name of the primary key in each table; you end up with loads of them in your model and can never be sure which you are referring to.
If you are using surrogate keys then I would suggest you use the same name throughout your model. You already have AccountID as a foreign key so use the same name for the primary.

Comment: Unfornately the naming convention was set by someone else so I can't really change it.  I appreciate your rationale though as I have the same concerns.

Comment: What is the entity of StatementHeader? Are statements with the same StatementHeaderID connected to each other in the real world, or is the AccountID and StatementDate all they share? The latter would make StatementHeader something like a calendar with SatementHeaderID as a date in disguise...

Comment: What is the relationship between Account and Branch? Should Branch have a foreign key AccountID, like the diagram seems to suggest?

Comment: "Statements" is a misnomer.  It should be called "StatementDetail", but I'm not responsible for the naming of the Entities.  An Account is like a customer.  A customer has a number of sub-branches.  These branches appear on the statement detail lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the StatementHeader then it should have the AccountID to keep the referential integrity.

However it may be better to remove the StatementHeader completely and move the StatementDate into the Statement record. This would make things cleaner and make the model better describe what you want.

Comment: This would just move the redundancy to the record though, as each record would have the same statement date.

Comment: It makes each statement record self contained which is good. 

Not all redundancy is bad - in this case the performance will be better because you can eliminate a join to get the date.

I appreciate that in situations where the statement date may change then having a 'StatementHeader' table allows manipulation of the date, but unless I'm wrong statement dates don't often change in this scenario so it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

As a statement is historical, and usually read only, data some redundency is fine. I agree with Richard Harrison and would move both [AccountID] and [StatementDate] in to the [Statement] table; my reasoning being you say that an account has many branches so you will be genereating a statement for an Account.

Storing all this data in the same place will reduce joins and speed up reporting, which i assume is the reason for this database.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, (real or perceived) redundancy is a consequence of a business rule. In this case, the business rule is: "a statement that is issued to an account shall contain only transactions for branches that belong to that particular account."

To enforce that rule, you could try to come up with a database schema that makes it impossible to violate it, or enforce it explicitly with a constraint or trigger. And that seems to be easier with StatementHeader.AccountID. In Oracle, you could write something like this:

```
create or replace trigger statement_has_unique_account
before insert or update on Statement
referencing old as old new as new
for each row
declare
  m integer;
  n integer;
begin
  select b.AccountID
  into m
  from Branch b 
  where b.ID = new.BranchID;

  select s.AccountID
  into n
  from StatementHeader s
  where s.ID = new.StatementID;

  if m <> n then
    raise_application_error(-1000, 'No way!');
  end if;
end;
```

Without AccountID in StatementHeader, you'd have to write a comparison with all the other AccountIDs from all other Statements that share the same StatementID, resulting in a more complicated sequence of statements.

So i would keep AccountID as a foreign key in StatementHeader and enforce the business rule explicitly with a trigger.